# Draw shapes in webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5-canvas, css-shapes

I have to make some shapes in my website, I need to put some background for the shapes, and it should change the background when I hover the cursor, how do i develop this, can I develop it using pure css or html canvas is required, I am attaching the demo image of the shape here. for the image given below each section is different shapes. any small help will be appreciated

[image]

Comment: where is your trial code?

Comment: Not the place to solve your home work; still here you can have helpful article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes

Comment: This will help you --> http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/12/21/slopy-elements-with-css3/ try for yourself and if you stuck then post it here with trial code as @vikrant said.

Comment: Go through [this](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

Comment: @Vikrant Since the code is too long I cant paste it here, I have done it using transform:skew(); attribute, and positioned using left,top,right,bottom attributes, but its not working in proper.

Comment: atleast you can JSfiddle it here : https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Vikrant I have tried that too, but since the css is spread all over in my project it is not working in jsfiddele, actually it is a team project,

Comment: @Vikrant and I just wanted to know wether it is possible with html5 canvas and will it be a risky process ?

Comment: @cybro, that's what there in my suggested link!

Answer (score 1):

How about this i used svg

```html
<svg width="1000" height="1000">

  <defs>
    <pattern id="image1" width="200" height="100">
      <image xlink:href="https://placekitten.com/g/200/302" width="300" height="200" x="-100" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>

  <defs>
    <pattern id="image2" width="200" height="100">
      <image xlink:href="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300" width="300" height="200" x="-100" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>

  <defs>
    <pattern id="image3" width="200" height="100">
      <image xlink:href="https://placekitten.com/g/200/301" width="300" height="200" x="-100" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>

  <defs>
    <pattern id="image4" width="200" height="100">
      <image xlink:href="https://placekitten.com/g/200/302" width="300" height="300" x="-100" y="10" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>

  <path d="m 100 20 l 100 0 -20 100 -100 0" stroke="orange" fill="url(#image1)" />
  <path d="m 80 120 l 100 0 -20 100 -100 0" stroke="green" fill="url(#image2)" />
  <path d="m 60 220 l 100 0 -20 100 -100 0" stroke="blue" fill="url(#image3)" />
  <path d="m 210 60 l -50 260 100 0" fill="url(#image4)" />
  <path d="m 350 20 l -130 40 15 80 130 -40" fill="url(#image1)" />
  <path d="m 365 100 l -100 30 20 90 100 -30" stroke="green" fill="url(#image2)" />
  <path d="m 385 190 l -100 30 20 90 100 -30" stroke="green" fill="url(#image3)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: this is seems to be good, let em check